# Why was the Super dropped from the titles of the Mario Kart games?

Tags: mario-kart-64

Back in the NES and SNES days, it was Super Mario Bros., Super Mario Kart, Super Mario This'n'That etc. I know that some SNES games used Super to indicate that they were indeed SNES games, and often sequels (of sorts) to NES games from before. But that didn't seem to apply to Mario games, which always had Super Mario in the title before.

This all changed from Mario Kart 64 onwards - while Super Mario 64, Sunshine, Galaxy and its sequel kept the Super naming convention, as did the Super Smash Bros. series, Mario Kart and Mario Party did not. I read somewhere that Mario Kart 64 was originally going to use Super in its name, but this was changed at some point in development and I don't know why. I can't imagine Super being a cause of confusion; I wouldn't have thought people would get mixed up and assume it's a SNES game or something, as such confusion didn't occur with main platform games which kept the Super naming convention.

So I'd be interested to know, if anyone was working in the industry back then and can shed some light on this. Cheers and happy gaming!

Answer (score 5):

Based on the list in Wikipedia, reproduced below, it appears that the "Super" was only ever in one game, at least at the front of the title.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Kart

- 1992 - **Super** Mario Kart - SNES
- 1996 - Mario Kart 64 - Nintendo 64
- 2001 - Mario Kart: **Super** Circuit - Game Boy Advance
- 2003 - Mario Kart: Double Dash!! - Nintendo GameCube
- 2005 - Mario Kart DS - Nintendo DS
- 2008 - Mario Kart Wii - Wii
- 2011 - Mario Kart 7 - Nintendo 3DS
- 2014 - Mario Kart 8 - Wii U
- 2017 - Mario Kart 8 Deluxe - Nintendo Switch
- 2019 - Mario Kart Tour - Android/iOS
- 2020 - Mario Kart Live: Home Circuit

So it seems likely that the "Super" was a nod to the system it came out on, the Super NES.  Other games in the series have similar naming after their systems: Mario Kart 64, Mario Kart DS, and Mario Kart Wii.